# How to securely embed a private Google Data studio report without a user needing a Google account

Tags: authentication, cookies, iframe, looker-studio

Is there any way to embed a **private** report (i.e. *Link-Sharing* set to OFF) in a site where the user does not have to be signed in to a Google account which has view permissions on the report? I understand from [this](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7450249?hl=en#how-embedding-works) piece of documentation that a private report can be viewed in an iframe only if the viewer is currently signed into a Google account which the report has been shared with.

This is not a feasible option in this case, and it comes down to two factors:

1. The client requires **complete** security of their reports.
2. The client, due to security reasons within their company, **cannot** create or use a Google account.

This means the only solution is for a 'service' type Google account to be created which authenticates with Google from within the application side of things, without relying on user input.

I guess that the document that loads within the iframe looks for a Google authentication cookie in the browser session of the user in order to authenticate access, so this seems like something that cannot be injected by the server or automated on the client (correct me if I'm wrong). Plus any kind of attempt to script a login through the iframe will result in some cross domain issues.

So, if there is some sort of official authentication technique which can achieve what I'm looking for, and have managed to overlook, it would be great if somebody could point that out! If not, if anyone has any ideas on a less neat and tidy way of doing this, I'd be equally as grateful!

Thanks

Comment: Are you absolutely sure, given the criteria you list, that GDS is an appropriate mechanism for this requirement at all? I'd be checking that if I were you (including checking that they are happy with the idea of a Google 'service account').

Comment: It turns out GDS, whilst capable of everything we need to get out of a BI dashboard, did fall short due to the frankly odd request to not use Google accounts. Unfortunately this request wasn't made until the dashboard was practically complete, hence the attempt to salvage the work already put in! We've now made the move to Pentaho, which hopefully fits their bizarre criteria. Thanks for your point though!

Comment: Not bizarre really, they may simply need to keep the data more private than public cloud access would permit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not share an active/live dashboard but you can deliver a password protected version of you report via PDF. To the farthest left of the "Edit" button you´ll see the "Download Report" feature.

Answer (score 6):

(coming late to the party, I'm aware, but stumbled upon this myself just now and believe I found an answer:)

When embedding a report, you are able to send a token via their community connectors to give specific viewing rights depending on who that is on the platform. I guess this wasn't available at the time posting this question, but sounds like a viable option now - read more: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials